# Interpret the QQ plot of multilevel logistic regression

Tags: r, qq-plot

I'm doing multilevel logistic model in R. To check the model diagnostic, I draw the following QQ plot. But it seems hard to say in which way it skews. I'm a bit confused what conclusion can we draw from this plot and what can we do to fix the problem?
[image]

Comment: With the binary nature of the dependent variable, I don’t think the QQ plot provides any insights.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Can i ask one more question, if QQ plot is not suitable for binary dependent variable, then what kind of diagnostic plot is suitable for the logistic regression